# How to perform inner join with Jpa Query methods/JpaRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to fetch data with one-to-many relation with inner join only.I can easily achieve the above using written direct HQL like this:

```
@Query("select distinct b from Batch b inner join fetch b.transactions")
```

But i dont want to write query as i am using JpaRepository interface which gives us very useful feature of **Query By Method**.

I also tried this.

```
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "transactions" } )
    List<Batch> findDistinctByIdNotNull();
```

This avoids N+1 problem but performs left outer join between batch & transaction entity. Can any one help how to perform inner join with using Query method feature??

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't just use that query, if you already have one that works? Spring Data repositories are great, but they can't cover every contingency.

Comment: @chrylis  95% of project is already using Spring data repositories. that's why i want to follow the same paradigms. however if it is not possible with data repositories then there is no confinement with that HQL Query.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query